# Как сделать такое главное меню? (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, svg

[image]

Как можно сделать вот такую волнистую линию у главного меню?

Comment: Нашел решение: 1)В paint обрезал белую область волшебной палочкой 2) Вставил картинку через background: url() и растянул repeat-y

Comment: Ответ потом оформите, чтоб закрыть вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Можно использовать изображение с куском волны и применить это изображение как фон меню с повторением по координате-x;

   ```
   background: url('волна.png') left top repeat-x;
   ```

   в качестве изображения можно использовать svg, но тогда необходимо будет указать     background-size.
2. Можно использовать [svg pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns)

   ```css
   html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}
   div{
     background: url('https://i.imgur.com/S1DAySp.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
     overflow:hidden;
   }

   svg{
     display:block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div>
     <svg viewbox="0 0 100 10">
       <pattern x="1" id="waves" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
         <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M10,0v5C8.3,6.7,6.7,6.7,5,5S1.7,3.3,0,5l0-5"/>
       </pattern>
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10" fill="url(#waves)"/>
     </svg>
     <p>контент</p>
     <p>контент</p>
     <p>контент</p>
     <p>контент</p>
     <p>контент</p>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: любой svg-редактор подойдет для рисования таких волн

Comment: в данном случае отрисована часть волны и потом, применив svg pattern (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns) можно размножить.

Comment: руками :) в редакторе ставишь 5 точек, выбираешь изгиб при построении линий, ничего сложного.